# Setting only GitHub (not Twitter) displays GitHub as "twitter"

Tags: bug, status-norepro, developer-story

I set my location, website and GitHub profile, leaving Twitter empty. The [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/123456?view=Timeline) looks like:

> NorthPole  [https://foo.bar](http://foo.bar) twitter_logo Twitter github_logo [nicdumz](http://github.com/nicdumz)

With AdBlock turned on, the .twitter-logo and .github-logo CSS classes do not show up, in turn rendering into:

> NorthPole  [https://foo.bar](http://foo.bar) Twitter [nicdumz](http://github.com/nicdumz)

In the current situation, it makes it look like `nicdumz` is my Twitter username, when it's actually my GitHub.

Comment: I believe that Twitter text is there to remind you that you *can* add a Twitter handle and that it would show up there if you added it. It's actually a bit clearer on the actual page because of the Twitter icon to the left of the "Twitter", and the GitHub icon to the left of the GitHub user name.

Answer (score 2):

I've checked your dev story and it seems OK, without any Twitter mention.
Can you still repro?

[image: dev story]

Comment: Missed the original answer/question. Edited the question to clarify. You're correct that the final, rendered profile is fine. The timeline, as shown in the edit UI though, is confusing