# Twitter still included in developer story when empty

Tags: feature-request, bug, developer-story

When you don't enter a Twitter profile in the developer story, it still says 'Twitter' on the developer story view.

My settings:

> [image]

The developer story view:

> [image]

The traditional view does not have this problem:

> [image]

Or is this by design, to push people to use twitter?

**Edit**: it seems this only happens when you are logged in, so then it's just a reminder that you *could* add a Twitter account? Then perhaps it could be a link to the form to add a Twitter profile, and read something like "Add Twitter". That would be clearer to me.

Comment: May be related to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336130/1544337, though I don't quite understand what that question is actually asking.